# cache friendly way to add to arrays of ints

Tags: swift, caching, optimization

I have become more mindful of optimizing my code for the cache. I am curious which of the following would be a more cache friendly way to add two arrays. The code is in swift.

```
struct A {
    var x, y, z: [Int]
}
func add1(a: inout [A]) {
    for i in 0 ..< a.count {
        a[i].z = a[i].x + a[i].y
    }
}
func add2(x: [Int], y:[Int], z: inout [Int]) {
    for i in 0 ..< x.count {
        z[i] = x[i] + y[i]
    }
}
```

My concern is that in `add2` the benefits of locality may be diminished since `x`, `y` and `z` need not be near one another in memory. For example suppose `x[0]` is loaded into cache, then `y[0]` is loaded into cache. Could the data near `y[0]` overwrite in cache the data near `x[0]`, so that a new fetch from ram is needed to load `x[1]`? And if so would `add1` resolve this issue?

Comment: But these `add1` and `add2` functions do a fundamentally different thing, was that just a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An access pattern like in `add2` is potentially a problem on a processor with a direct mapped cache, and still only if the addresses of the arrays are exactly the wrong thing. With a typical 4 or 8-way set-associative cache there isn't really a problem here, even with maximally unlucky array addresses: if the blocks containing `x[0]` and `y[0]` and `z[0]` all map to the same set, they will still fit and not eject each other. Direct mapped caches do suffer the conflict misses that you are worried about, which is part of why they are rare now, but there are more reasons.

Actually an access pattern like that of `add2` is very nice, since depending on the operation being performed it can also be auto-vectorized. That isn't done with the overflow-checked addition (checked addition is hard to vectorize), but with the wrapping addition `&+` the [compiler can use](https://godbolt.org/g/cjT6jx) `movdqu` to load and store two Ints at the same time, and `paddq` to add two Ints at the same time.